# Multiple selection from Dropdown-List not Dropdown List-box

Tags: javascript, html

My question is, I want to select multiple values from dropdown list not List-box.
meance, I mean to say when we select multiple values dropdown we have use 
`<select multiple="multiple">` but I don't want this, I want selected Id's from dropdown and store it in var. basically, multiple selection we use dropdown list-box like (dropdown paragraph).
I want dropdown that sliddown when we click and after select it slideup again.likewise, I want mutiple selection in that.
can we approach that? I did not got in any logic?

Comment: Take a look at select2:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html and the multiple select boxes example.

Comment: @CronbachAlpha exactly..but can I use selected value ID used in var to ,So will get on another page in PHP